# How do I properly test weakly/strong-named internal class within one NUnit project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, .net-assembly

I have a UnitTest project to test both weakly-named and strong-named projects.
Since I want to test some internal class in a strong-named project, I can set `InternalsVisibleTo` but I will have to make my test project signed.

In that case I am not able to reference any weakly assembly in my test project anymore since my test assembly is strong-named!

> A strong-named assembly can only use types from other strong-named assemblies. Otherwise, the integrity of the strong-named assembly would be compromised.

I see two solution:

- Make all weakly-named projects signed, which brings impact to existing projects(does not serve my testing purpose. I don't want to sign them)
- Create two UnitTests, which makes things complicated.

If I have a module under test that uses both weakly&strong-named assemblies. Is there any better way to test it as "friend"?

Comment: Creating separate test assemblies would be my first thought. Can you enlarge on how this "makes things complicated" for you? It's very common to have four or five test assemblies for a particular application and I've had projects with up to 64 of them.

Comment: @Charlie OK, that might be the correct solution.  I should say "relatively" complicated. e.g. I need to add multiple test assembly friends, and sign/unsign them

Comment: If you test the unsigned ones using a separate assembly you don't need to sign them if you avoid accessing internal fields... If you can't do that, then of course you are back to the original problem.